# Wifi (Whole Wifi, not only the pi's) doesn't work when the Pi is connected. How Do I fix that?

Tags: pi-zero-w, retropie

If I connect my Pi Zero W to Power, My Home Wifi stops working. If I ask my Echo what Time it is before its plugged in, it will say the time. After that. It wont. Same for Opening Websites How Do I fix that?
I tried

- Restarting the Pi
- Restarting the Network

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: you have described a portion of your observations, but you have not asked a question

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have done a conflicting setup with your WiFi, maybe double ip addresses, more than one dhcp server or creating a broadcast storm or something like that that will break down your network.

You asked how to fix that. You should flash [Raspbian Buster](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) to the SD Card and enable WiFi on it as described at [Wireless connectivity](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/README.md). This is known to work out of the box and does not conflict with your network setting.